# Lock for preventing concurrent access in client data

Tags: java, performance, multithreading, rest, atomic

I am trying to implement lock by which I don't want to have reads from happening whenever I am doing a write.

Here is my `ClientData` class in which I am using `CountDownLatch`:

```
public class ClientData {

    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> primaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> secondaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> tertiaryMapping = new AtomicReference<>();

    // should this be initialized as 1?
    private static final CountDownLatch hasBeenInitialized = new CountDownLatch(1) 

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getPrimaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return primaryMapping.get();
    }

    public static void setPrimaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        primaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getSecondaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return secondaryMapping.get();
    }       

    public static void setSecondaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        secondaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getTertiaryMapping() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return tertiaryMapping.get();
    }       

    public static void setTertiaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        tertiaryMapping.set(map);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }       
}
```

I need to wait on the `get` calls on three `AtomicReferences` I have. Once all the writes has been done on the three `AtomicReferences` I have with the `set` call, I'll allow making the call to three getters which I have.

I decided to use `CountDownLatch` which I have initialized as `1`. Do I need to initialize it to `3`? And every time before I do the first set on a new update, should I need to reset the countdown latch back to 3? I will be setting those three `AtomicReferences` in three separate statements.

Is there something wrong here? Some other threads have to read the data from these `AtomicReferences` once they have been set.

Here is my background thread code which will get the data from the URL, parse it and store it in a `ClientData`class variable:

```
public class TempScheduler {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        public void startScheduler() {
            final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                try {
                    callServers();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        }
    }

    // call the servers and get the data and then parse 
    // the response.
    private void callServers() {
        String url = "url";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        parseResponse(response);

    }

    // parse the response and store it in a variable
    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryTables = null;
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryTables = null;

        //...

        // store the data in ClientData class variables which can be
        // used by other threads
        ClientData.setPrimaryMapping(primaryTables);
        ClientData.setSecondaryMapping(secondaryTables);
        ClientData.setTertiaryMapping(tertiaryTables);
    }
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Also, is there any way I can use one latch instead of three separate latches here?

Comment: Is this a Bean or something (i.e. why do you need three setters... can't you `setMappings(primary, secondary, tertiary)`) ?

Comment: @rolfl: I have updated the question. Can you take a look whether that's what you were suggesting? And with the above code, I can use `countdownlatch` as 1, right? I still doubt whatever I did is right?

Comment: From your code it seems that the background thread will be _overwriting_ the maps every so often. Is that correct?

Comment: @David: Not everytime, only whenever there is any change. For the first time, when the code is run, then it will add the values in the map. And then after that, whenever there is any change then only it will update those maps and that change will happen only once in three months max. So that means if the code is running for three months, and if we decide to change something on the service url which my background thread is parsing, and if there is any change, then only it will update those three maps.

Comment: @Webby One change every three months is more than none which means this code must accept a new set of maps at any time.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: By `this code`, you mean to say `ClientData` class. Right?

Comment: For iterative reviews, [please post a separate question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763). I have rolled back to Rev 1.

Comment: @200_success: Sure I will do that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you must be able to swap in a new set of maps at any time--even if only once every three months--requires a design change. Here are the requirements as I understand them:

- Reads block until all three maps have been set the first time.
- Reads receive a consistent set of maps. In other words, you cannot return the old secondary map after returning the new primary map.

Taken together, you really must combine the maps into a new data structure which is returned to clients and replaced in whole by the background thread. Storing it in its own atomic reference allows this new class to avoid concurrency and locks altogether.

- Keep the latch to block reads before the first set of maps have been loaded.
- Combine the three maps in a simple data holder.
- Store the data holder in an atomic reference (if necessary) instead of each map individually.
- Set all three maps in one call by storing a new data holder instance. Since all three are stored in one call, the latch can use an initial count of 1.

**Update**

Now let's throw some code behind the above changes.

```
public class ClientData {

    public static class Mappings {
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary;
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary;
        public final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary;

        public Mappings(
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary
        ) {
            this.primary = primary;
            this.secondary = secondary;
            this.tertiary = tertiary;
        }
    }

    private static final AtomicReference<Mappings> mappings = new AtomicReference<>();
    private static final CountDownLatch hasBeenInitialized = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static Mappings getMappings() {
        try {
            hasBeenInitialized.await();
            return mappings.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // @rolfl covered this
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void setMappings(
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary,
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary,
        Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary
    ) {
        setMappings(new Mappings(primary, secondary, tertiary));
    }

    public static void setMappings(Mappings newMappings) {
        mappings.set(newMappings);
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    }
}
```

There are some other improvements I would suggest but did not implement.

- Avoid using static methods when possible to ease testing and alternate implementations.
- The atomic reference may not actually be required since both get and set operations synchronize on `hasBeenInitialized`.
- If clients of `ClientData` can handle receiving empty mappings, you can drop the latch and initialize the class with three empty maps. This would reduce all synchronization to the atomic reference.

Comment: For your second point, Yes, I can still return old map while I am updating the maps second time. But as soon the update is done, I should return new maps value. Sorry for the confusion if I was not clear earlier.

Comment: But is it okay to return the new first map and the old second/third map to the same caller? If they are related, you should return either all old maps or new maps--never a random mix of the two _to the same caller_.

Comment: No. In that case, it should either return all the old maps or all the new maps , not intermix of it. Right now I am using @rolfl suggestion which uses the `ReentrantLock`. Do you think this use case will be solve by that or there will be any problem?

Comment: @Webby My understanding of rolfl's code is that it doesn't allow setting a new trio of maps. Did I miss something?

Comment: He has the set calls right which I can use to set them up?

Comment: No, this code blocks changing the set of maps once set: `throw new IllegalStateException("All the maps are already set");`

Comment: @Webby See my update with code. I'll hang out in chat for a bit, too.

Comment: hey are you around?  I have a basic question on this solution. It's been a long time and I am still using it in production. I had some confusion so wanted to check on this.

Comment: @lining Sure, what's your question?

Answer (score 5):

AtomicReferences are a great construct when you have just one item that needs to be kept in a sane state ina  multithreaded environment. Your code is trying to juggle three, and ensure they all have a sane state at the right times, and, for that, you need something bigger than the AtomicReference.

You have elected to use the CountDownLatch. This, frankly, in this situation, is not the right choice. The right choice is to use basic synchronization, or to use a ReentrantLock.

I have taken the liberty of rewriting your class using a Lock, with a dependent Condition, and no other java.util.* components.

This code waits for all three maps to be set, and, when they are, it signals the Condition, and the getters are 'released'.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ClientData {

    private static final class MapContainer {
        private Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> value = null;

        public Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

    }

    private static final MapContainer primaryMapping = new MapContainer();
    private static final MapContainer secondaryMapping = new MapContainer();
    private static final MapContainer tertiaryMapping = new MapContainer();
    private static final MapContainer[] containers = {primaryMapping, secondaryMapping, tertiaryMapping};
    private static boolean allset = false;
    private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static final Condition allsetnow = lock.newCondition();

    private static final Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getMapping(MapContainer container) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!allset) {
                allsetnow.await();
            }
            return container.getValue();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // reset interruptedd state.
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }

    }

    private static final void setMapping(MapContainer container, Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> value) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null Map cannot be used");
        }
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (allset) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("All the maps are already set");
            }
            if (container.getValue() != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change the value in a mapping");
            }
            container.setValue(value);
            for (MapContainer cont : containers) {
                if (cont.getValue() == null) {
                    // not all values are set....
                    return;
                }
            }
            allset = true;
            allsetnow.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getPrimaryMapping() {
        return getMapping(primaryMapping);
    }

    public static void setPrimaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        setMapping(primaryMapping, map);
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getSecondaryMapping() {
        return getMapping(secondaryMapping);
    }

    public static void setSecondaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        setMapping(secondaryMapping, map);
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getTertiaryMapping() {
        return getMapping(tertiaryMapping);
    }       

    public static void setTertiaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
        setMapping(tertiaryMapping, map);
    }       
}
```

It would be better if, instead of three separate `set*` methods, you had just one method that set all three maps.... if you did, the code would look simpler, like:

```
    public static void setAllMappings(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary,
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary) {
        lock.lock();
        try{
            if (allset) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Maps already set");
            }
            primaryMapping.setValue(primary);
            secondaryMapping.setValue(secondary);
            tertiaryMapping.setValue(tertiary);
            allset = true;
            allsetnow.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Other problems in your code are:

- your use of the CountDownLatch should have started at `3`
- it is a problem if the same setter is called twice (will reach 0 before all maps are set)
- When handling InterruptedException, you should leave the thread in an appropriate state. In your case, by catching it, and wrapping it in a RuntimeException, you should also reset the interrupted state of the thread.

**Edit:**

If you were to adjust the way you set the values in the AtomicReference, then the Concerns I have with the CountDownLatch would be mitigated. Consider the following:

```
public static void setPrimaryMapping(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
    if (map != null && primaryMapping.compareAndSet(null, map)) {
        hasBeenInitialized.countDown();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalSateException("Map has already been set... cannot double-set it");
    }
}
```

The above will mean that each Map can be set only once, and the countdownlatch will work well enough (if initialized with `3`).

Note that with the CountDown latch, and 3 AtomicReferences, that you have 4 locks that all need to work together, when really, the only one that is important for the actual acess restrictions is the CountDownLatch. That is the reason I don't like the solution with the atomics, and the latch, because the same can be accomplished with just a single lock, which applies the access and concurrency restrictions in a more consistent/logical way.

**Edit 2**

Simple traditional synchronization mechanism.

```
import java.util.Map;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ClientData {

    private static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryMap = null;
    private static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondaryMap = null;
    private static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiaryMap = null;
    private static boolean allset = false;
    private static final Object synclock = new Object();

    private static final void waitTillSet() {
        try {
            while (!allset) {
                synclock.wait();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void setAllMappings(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> primary, 
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> secondary, 
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> tertiary) {
        synchronized (synclock) {
            if (allset) {
                return; // throw exception otherwise.
            }
            primaryMap = primary;
            secondaryMap = secondary;
            tertiaryMap = tertiary;
            allset = true;
            synclock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getPrimaryMapping() {
        synchronized (synclock) {
            waitTillSet();
            return primaryMap;
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getSecondaryMapping() {
        synchronized (synclock) {
            waitTillSet();
            return secondaryMap;
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getTertiaryMapping() {
        synchronized (synclock) {
            waitTillSet();
            return tertiaryMap;
        }
    }       

}
```

Comment: @Webby - the first block of code is compatible with what you originally posted. It has three separate `set*Mapping(Map...)` calls. The second block of code is an alternate mechanism that sets all three at once, and does not need to check if the others have been set.... You should either use the code as it is in the first block, or, replace the three `set*Mapping` methods in the first block with the one `setAllMappings(...)` in the second block

Comment: Yup.. I figure that one out after taking a close look at the code. In general what is the benefit of `ReentrantLock` as compared to I was using `CountDownLatch` earlier? And here `ReentrantLock` means, that as soon as the write is done on those three maps, then only you will be able to read the data from those three maps, right? And again, if the writes are happening to those three tables, then the call will be blocked and whenever the writes are done, then the thread will be able to read the data again using the getters?

Comment: @Webby - Hmmm ... those are huge things to answer.... The big problem I have with the countdownLatch is the unsafe setting... you can set the same map 3 times, and trigger the getters... Let me add an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. In this case also with `ReentrantLock`, once the first write is done on all three tables, then there won't be any locking happening on the get calls, Right? Only for the first write to those three tables, there will be a locking on `get` calls to those three tables otherwise there won't be any?

Comment: There will always be locking on the `get*(...)` calls, (whether with the CountdownLatch or the ReentrantLock). There will only be ***blocking*** if the gets are called before all three sets are called.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That makes sense. And I am definitely thinking to go with `ReentrantLock` as in my case performance is really really important. So I can safely assume, for the first `set` to all three tables, all three `gets` will be **blocked** for sure. And as soon as the `set` is done on all three tables, then there won't be any **blocking** on the get calls? Right?